# Array/Pointer: Left operand must be l-value

Tags: c

I've just started out with C and I'm struggling to get to grips when mixing pointers and arrays.

I am getting the following error:

**error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value**

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct PersonDetails {
    char *name;
    int *phoneNumber;
};

int* getPhoneNumber(struct PersonDetails *phoneBook[], char* name);

int main() {

    struct PersonDetails a;
    struct PersonDetails b;
    struct PersonDetails people[2];
    struct PersonDetails *ptr[2];
    char aName = 'T';
    int aNum = 123;
    char bName = 'O';
    int bNum = 456;
    a.name = &aName;
    a.phoneNumber = &aNum;
    b.name = &bName;
    b.phoneNumber = &bNum;

    people[0] = a;
    people[1] = b;
    ptr = &people;

    printf("%d", *getPhoneNumber(ptr, aName));

    return 0;
}

int* getPhoneNumber(struct PersonDetails *phoneBook[], char* name) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (*phoneBook[i]->name == *name) return phoneBook[i]->phoneNumber;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It's happening on the line:

```
ptr = &people;
```

**Edited Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct PersonDetails {
    char *name;
    int *phoneNumber;
};

int* getPhoneNumber(struct PersonDetails *phoneBook[], char* name);

int main() {
    struct PersonDetails a;
    struct PersonDetails b;
    struct PersonDetails people[2];
    struct PersonDetails *ptr;
    char aName = 'T';
    int aNum = 123;
    char bName = 'O';
    int bNum = 456;
    a.name = &aName;
    a.phoneNumber = &aNum;
    b.name = &bName;
    b.phoneNumber = &bNum;

    people[0] = a;
    people[1] = b;

    ptr = people;

    printf("%d", *getPhoneNumber(ptr, aName));

    return 0;
}

int* getPhoneNumber(struct PersonDetails *phoneBook, char* name) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (*phoneBook[i].name == *name) return phoneBook[i].phoneNumber;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because ptr is an array, not a pointer. You can't override the address it holds. Also, the types don't match.

Comment: The expression `*phoneBook[i]->name == *name` will only compare the first letter, if you want to compare string use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you declared `ptr` to be an array of pointers to `struct PersonDetail`?

Comment: @alk Because the method getPhoneNumber requires the parameter struct PersonDetails *phoneBook[]

Comment: `ptr[0]=&people[0];ptr[1]=&people[1];printf("%d", *getPhoneNumber(ptr, &aName));`

Comment: Why does `getPhoneNumber()` require that eccentric type?  There must be a reason why you chose to use it (like "the teacher set that in the question I'm working on").  Otherwise, it seems more likely that the parameter should be either `struct PersonDetail *who` or `struct PersonDetail who[]` — which, in the context of a function's parameter list (and only in the context of a function's parameter list) amounts to the same thing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Originally it was `PersonDetails *phoneBook`, but I didn't think that would work? Am I wrong in thinking that, and how would I go about using that to find a number using a name?

Comment: Assuming you mean `struct PersonDetails *phoneBook` (there isn't a type `PersonDetails` in  your code, but there is `struct PersonDetails`), then that would work fine.  It is a pointer parameter that can either point to a single person's details, or to the start of an array of people's details.  Inside the function, as long as you know that the array is big enough, you can use `phoneBook[i].name` or `phoneBook[i].number` with care.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh wow, thank you, that helps so much. So i would change `ptr` to just `struct PersonDetails *ptr;` as opposed to an array of pointers?

Comment: Yes — using `struct PersonDetails *ptr;` is all you need.  You are (accidentally) delving into more complex structures which do have a place for more complex situations, which is why no-one could say "this is wrong", but they're currently beyond what you need, or what you currently understand.  That's OK; what you've just learned probably covers 95% or more of real life use cases.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Okay, it all compiles now, but crashes when executed. I have a feeling it has something to do with how I'm assigning both `ptr` and `people`. Do I just delete the `people` array? I've added an edited section in the question if you could have a look for me please?

Comment: You are now passing a `char` value, `aName`, where the function expects a `char *`, which would be `&aName`. The function prototype at the top also doesn't match the function definition; the definition is correct.  You need to remove either the `*` or the `[]` but not both from the prototype.  With that, it 'works'.  Be aware that you don't have strings (not null terminated) so you can't do string comparison (`strcmp()`), but that's probably the next phase.  Your compiler should have been generating warnings; pay heed.  Remember, it knows a lot more about C than you do at the moment!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh wow, it works! Thank you so much. Would you like to move this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring sundry comments of mine in dialogue with the OP into an answer*</sup>

> Because the method `getPhoneNumber()` requires the parameter `struct PersonDetails *phoneBook[]`.

Why does `getPhoneNumber()` require that eccentric type? There must be a reason why you chose to use it (like "the teacher set that in the question I'm working on"). Otherwise, it seems more likely that the parameter should be either `struct PersonDetail *who` or `struct PersonDetail who[]` — which, in the context of a function's parameter list (and only in the context of a function's parameter list) amounts to the same thing.

> Originally it was `PersonDetails *phoneBook`, but I didn't think that would work? Am I wrong in thinking that, and how would I go about using that to find a number using a name?

Assuming you mean `struct PersonDetails *phoneBook` (there isn't a type `PersonDetails` in your code, but there is the type `struct PersonDetails`), then that would work fine. It is a pointer parameter that can either point to a single person's details, or to the start of an array of people's details. Inside the function, as long as you know that the array is big enough, you can use `phoneBook[i].name` or `phoneBook[i].number` with care.  (Or, indeed, `phoneBook->name` and `phoneBook->number`, which refer to the single element pointed at by `phoneBook`, or you can think of it as using an effective subscript of 0.)

> Oh wow, thank you, that helps so much. So I would change ptr to just `struct PersonDetails *ptr;` as opposed to an array of pointers?

Yes — using `struct PersonDetails *ptr;` is all you need. You are (accidentally) delving into more complex structures which do have a place in more complex situations, which is why no-one could say "this is wrong", but they're currently beyond what you need, or what you currently understand. That's OK; what you've just learned probably covers 95% or more of real life use cases.

> Okay, it all compiles now, but crashes when executed. I have a feeling it has something to do with how I'm assigning both `ptr` and `people`. Do I just delete the `people` array? I've added an edited section in the question if you could have a look for me please?

You are now passing a `char` value, `aName`, where the function expects a `char *`, which would be `&aName`. The function prototype at the top also doesn't match the function definition; the definition is correct. You need to remove either the `*` or the `[]` but not both from the prototype. With that, it 'works'.

Be aware that you don't have strings (the `char *` values do not point to null terminated arrays of characters) so you can't do string comparison (`strcmp()`), but fixing that is probably the next phase of development.

Your compiler should have been generating warnings; pay heed. Remember, it knows a lot more about C than you do at the moment!

#### Working code

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct PersonDetails
{
    char *name;
    int *phoneNumber;
};

int *getPhoneNumber(struct PersonDetails *phoneBook, char *name);

int main(void)
{
    struct PersonDetails a;
    struct PersonDetails b;
    struct PersonDetails people[2];
    struct PersonDetails *ptr;
    char aName = 'T';
    int aNum = 123;
    char bName = 'O';
    int bNum = 456;
    a.name = &aName;
    a.phoneNumber = &aNum;
    b.name = &bName;
    b.phoneNumber = &bNum;

    people[0] = a;
    people[1] = b;

    ptr = people;

    printf("%d\n", *getPhoneNumber(ptr, &aName));

    return 0;
}

int *getPhoneNumber(struct PersonDetails *phoneBook, char *name)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (*phoneBook[i].name == *name)
            return phoneBook[i].phoneNumber;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that printing the result directly as shown will fail horribly (usually) if the 'name' is not found.  You'll be dereferencing a null pointer, which invokes undefined behaviour — A Bad Thing™!  You really need to use:

```
int *p_number = getPhoneNumber(ptr, &name);
if (p_number == NULL)
    printf("No entry for name %c\n", name);
else
    printf("Number for %c is %d\n", name, *p_number);
```

You should also review why you have `int *number;` instead of just `int number;` or `char *number;`.  The former is better if you simply store an unformatted integer; the latter is better if you might need to store `+44 1395 276679` or something like that, though you should then consider the relative merits of `char number[MAX_PHONE_NUMBER_STRING_LEN];` instead of a pointer.

Also, for more nearly general-purpose code, your function should probably be told how many entries there are in the phone-book, rather than using a hard-wired size of 2 (which is a pretty minimal phone-book by any standard):

```
int *getPhoneNumber(int n_entries, struct PersonDetails *phoneBook, char *name)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n_entries; i++)
    {
        if (*phoneBook[i].name == *name)
            return phoneBook[i].phoneNumber;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Where the number of entries in the array is a parameter.  Assuming you have C99 or C11, you could also sensibly write that as:

```
int *getPhoneNumber(int n_entries, struct PersonDetails phoneBook[n_entries], char *name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n_entries; i++)
    {
        if (*phoneBook[i].name == *name)
            return phoneBook[i].phoneNumber;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In both these last samples, I've not changed the data types in the structure (even though I think they should be changed).  I've also not added `const` qualifiers to the pointer/array or the name, even though both could legitimately be `const`-qualified.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct PersonDetails *ptr[2];
```

ptr is an array of pointers and array itself is never a modifiable value. lvalue should be some location where you store values(like variable). So this is an error.

Comment: You have to decide what you want to do.  Fixes include: `ptr[0] = people;` and `struct PersonDetails (*ptr)[2]; ptr = &people;`.

Comment: @ThomasOwers You can use a pointer to point to your structure like `ptr[0] = people`

Comment: There are 2 elements in each array, I guess he wants each pointer to point to the respective element (yes, a little pointless when you have indices, but i'm not judging)

Answer (score 0):

You define as follows -

```
struct PersonDetails people[2];
struct PersonDetails *ptr[2];
```

which means the `people` is a 2-element array of structs of type `PersonDetails`, while `ptr` is a 2-element array of pointers to such structs.

You can't override the address of an array, it's not just some pointer (although there are some mutual semantics), it's allocated on the stack.

If you meant each element in `ptr` to point to the respective `people` element, use a loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    ptr[i] = &people[i];
```

Also note that one of the effects of passing around all these pointers to simple variables defined in main, is that you can return a null pointer from `getPhoneNumber`, and pass it to printf - that would segfault

Answer (score 0):

- ptr is an array of pointers to struct PersonDetails, so ptr[0] and ptr[1]
  are pointers to struct PersonDetails, then you can asign the address of a variable of the type struct PersonDetails to each element of ptr.
- in C an array is something like a pointer (but it's not exactly the same) which points to a part of the
  memory (with the size of the type of variables times the numbers of elements of the array) where you can store one or more variables of one type, so in
  your example, you could see people like a pointer to struct PersonDetails, and ptr like a pointer to a pointer to struct PersonDetails.

So, with all that said, what you can do is ptr[0] = people or ptr[1] = people.